# How can I create a type hint that my returned list contains strings?

Tags: python, python-3.5, type-hinting

I want to use Type Hints in my Python program. How can I create Type Hints for complex data structures like

- lists with strings
- a generator returning integers?

**Example**

```
def names() -> list:
    # I would like to specify that the list contains strings?
    return ['Amelie', 'John', 'Carmen']

def numbers():
    # Which type should I specify for `numbers()`?
    for num in range(100):
        yield num
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the [`typing` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html); it contains *generics*, type objects you can use to specify containers with constraints on their contents:

```
import typing

def names() -> typing.List[str]:  # list object with strings
    return ['Amelie', 'John', 'Carmen']

def numbers() -> typing.Iterator[int]:  # iterator yielding integers
    for num in range(100):
        yield num
```

Depending on how you design your code and how you want to use the return value of `names()`, you could also use the [`types.Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Sequence) and [`types.MutableSequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.MutableSequence) types here, depending on wether or not you expect to be able to mutate the result.

A generator is a specific type of *iterator*, so `typing.Iterator` is appropriate here. If your generator also accepts `send()` values and uses `return` to set a `StopIteration` value, you can use the [`typing.Generator` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generator) too:

```
def filtered_numbers(filter) -> typing.Generator[int, int, float]:
    # contrived generator that filters numbers; returns percentage filtered.
    # first send a limit!
    matched = 0
    limit = yield
    yield  # one more yield to pause after sending
    for num in range(limit):
        if filter(num):
            yield num
            matched += 1
    return (matched / limit) * 100
```

If you are new to type hinting, then [PEP 483 – *The Theory of Type Hints*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/) may be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Since python 3.9, you can simply use the syntax below. No need for `import typing` module anymore.

```py
def names() -> list[str]:
```