# How are array typehints declared in Python?

Tags: python, type-hinting

Given this function:

```
def array_returner():
    return ["hello", "there"]
```

How would I typehint that this function returns an array of strings, without importing List (and using the `List[str]` syntax)?

Comment: Duplicate: [How to properly function annotate / type hint a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905597/how-to-properly-function-annotate-type-hint-a-list-of-strings)

Comment: Also: [Type hinting a list of a specified type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24853923/7851470)

Comment: @Georgy These questions address Lists, not arrays. I don't want to import List. (and `list[str]` evidently does not work)

Comment: I think you need exactly the list, as your example function returns a list, [not an "array"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514553/how-to-declare-an-array-in-python). Even if it's not the case, I don't get why you want to avoid using `List[str]`, and at the same time you accepted an answer that proposed it. Could you clarify, please?

Comment: Another duplicate: [How can I create a type hint that my returned list contains strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37386499/7851470)

Comment: @Georgy You are right, I misunderstood (however `[str]` works just fine?). Regarding my accepted answer it proposed both `List[str]` and `[str]`. As for why I would want to avoid importing List — mainly that I see no reason to import it if there is a syntax that lets me do without it. Is there any reason to use it (rather than this syntax)? I realise this might be somewhat off-topic though.

Comment: Using `[str]` is not a proper way to type hint a list of strings. You can check it, for example, [here](https://mypy-play.net/). It will give you the following error: "*Bracketed expression "[...]" is not valid as a type*... *Did you mean "List[...]"?*". I guess it's possible that your IDE can accept `[str]`, but I don't know how well it will work. I suggest not using this syntax, as it is [not documented](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/).

Comment: @Georgy Regarding how well it works, I get not warnings in Python 3.7.5. But, considering that it is undocumented — fair, I'll admit defeat. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like this

```
from typing import List
def array_returner() -> List[str]:
    pass
```

Since `python3.9`

```
def array_returner() -> list[str]:
    pass
```

Answer (score 13):

This is what you're looking for:

```
from typing import List

def array_returner() -> List[str]:
    return ["hello", "there"]
```